# How to install WebDriver++

Tags: c++, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to build this with CMake and it constantly fails when it says that the test folder does not contain a CMakeLists.txt.
The Author does not seem to be active there anymore as issues posted don't seem to be answered.
https://github.com/GermanAizek/webdriverxx

Originally i thought that i just needed the include folder to use the program but it fails
I have the selenium server running before executing this code tried both 4.0.0beta and 4.9.1.
Browser just shuts down immediately. and gives me an unhandled exception error.
sometimes it even asks for libcurl-d.dll

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <webdriverxx.h>

int main() {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    webdriverxx::Capabilities common;
    common.SetPlatform(webdriverxx::platform::Windows);

    webdriverxx::WebDriver firefox = webdriverxx::Start(webdriverxx::Firefox());

    firefox
        .Navigate("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent")
        /*
        .FindElement(webdriverxx::ByClass("class_name"))
        .SendKeys("Hello, world!")
        .Submit()
        */
        ;

    return 0;
}
```

Selenium server gives me this error:

```
WARNING: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finishJed, it is too late atvoa reSgicsrtieprt  ceormrpolr:et resoioun rcceo://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OnS.File:d iftilouns h" I/OO queued before profileBeforeChange"
hARNING: A blocker encountered an error whcile we were waiting.
WARNING: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
```

Am I doing something wrong?